# Domain of harmonic oscillator and spectral decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Consider Hermite operator (harmonic oscillator) $H=-\Delta+|x|^2.$
It is known that hermite functions  are eigen functions for $H$:
$$H(\Phi_\alpha)= (2|\alpha| +d) \Phi_{\alpha}, \quad (|\alpha |= \alpha_{1}+ ...+ \alpha_d, \alpha_{i}\in \mathbb N).$$
$( \Phi_\alpha(x) = \Pi_{j=1}^d  h_{\alpha_j}(x_j), \quad h_k(x) = (\sqrt{\pi}2^k k!)^{-1/2} (-1)^k e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}  \frac{d^k}{dx^k} e^{-x^2}), x\in \mathbb R^d$

Also it known that $\{\Phi_{\alpha}\}$ forms ONB for $L^2(\mathbb R^d): f= \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb N^d} \langle f, \Phi_{\alpha} \rangle \Phi_{\alpha}.$

> My Questions are following:
> (1) What is the domain of harmonic oscillator $H$? Can say it is $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$?
> (2) Can we say that $H$ is self-adjoint operator $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$?
> (3) Can we expect  to use spectral theorem to get the spectral decomposition for $H$, that
> $$Hf=\sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb N^d} (2|\alpha| +d) \langle f, \Phi_{\alpha} \rangle \Phi_{\alpha} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+d)P_kf$$
> where $P_kf(x) = \sum_{|\alpha|=k} \langle f,\Phi_\alpha\rangle \Phi_\alpha.$

---

My attempt:
"Spectral Theorem: Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$. Then there is a unique projection-valued measure $\mu^A$ on the spectrum $\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathbb R$ with values in the bounded operators $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ such that
$$
\int_{\sigma(A)}\lambda\,d\mu^A(\lambda)=A.
$$"

(i)We may wish to apply spectral theorem for $H$.
(ii)I think the spectrum of $H$, that is, $\sigma(H)=\{ 2|\alpha|+d: \alpha \in \mathbb N^d \}\subset \mathbb N$ (How should I justify this)

(please correct me if I'm wrong!!)
(iii) I wish to find spectral valued measure $\mu^H$ on $\sigma (H)$
(iv) How to interpret: $\int_{\sigma (H) } \lambda \mu^H(\lambda)$

Comment: The notion of "domain" of unbounded operators is a bit complicated... As is the notion of "self adjoint". The "spectral theorem" only makes good sense _after_ being confident of those more-basic things. What is your context, more precisely?

Comment: @paulgarrett: Thanks. I wish to understand the spectral decomposition for $H$ to study Hermite multiplier (harmonic analysis).

Comment: To prove that the spectrum is purely discrete, you probably want to show that a/the resolvent is _compact_, which needs to use some physical aspects of the situation (so that one can prove a Rellich-type lemma). With a semi-bounded operator like this, the Friedrichs self-adjoint extension of a symmetric operator such as "your operator restricted to test functions" has a readily-characterizable resolvent, by construction. Gerd Grubb's book "operators and distributions" gives a good discussion, in my opinion.

Comment: ... and/but the particulars about proving that _all_ the spectrum is what we think it is needs to use raising and lowering operators and so on... A special, separate argument.